# How to import a python function from a sibling folder

Tags: python, import

This question has been asked before. Even though I couldn't get an answer that solves this issue.

I have the following directory and subdirectories:

[image]

I have a function `hello()` in `test1.py` that I want to import in `test2.py`.

**test1.py:**

```
def hello():
  print("hello")
```

**test2.py:**

```
import demoA.test1 as test1

test1.hello()
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/hasli/Documents/Projects/test/demoB/test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import demoA.test1 as test1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

This is exactly as explained in https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/module-not-found-error-in-python-solved/ but I can't access `hello()`

I am using python 3: `Python 3.8.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add demoA to the [list of paths used for import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/850332).

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

import demoA.test1 as test1

test1.hello()
```

Comment: This works! However only works if the script is being executed from the file's folder.
As far as I understood from the other answer suggested by you, the only way around would be to append the path to the file, right?